# Kafka to Flink message processing issue

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

We have kafka -> flink -> MongoDB real time message streaming application.
When we send small number of messages (10-100) everything works fine.
But when we send 1000's of messages the behavior at the flink processing side is very strange.
1. The business method at the flink side is executed by more than one thread at the same time resulting in incorrect behavior.
2. If any of the message processing failed then last few successfully processed messages are getting re-delivered resulting in duplicate message consumption.

Here are my kafka , flink configurations :-
**Kafka**
Confluent Kafka , one topic with 8 partitions.
**Flink Cluster**
One job manager and two task managers.
Both the task managers have 8 core CPUs.
flink-conf.yaml:

```
taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 8  
parallelism.default: 8
```

**Flink Job Details**
Put FlinkKafkaConsumer011 properties as : *prop.put("enable.auto.commit", "true")*
CheckpointMode : Exactly Once
Flink started with Parallelism 8 : *flink run -p 8*

Comment: Are you using state values in your flink functions? If you mark .sequential() or setParallelism(1) , does ir work well (but slow haha)?

Comment: Yeah, well if You set parallelism 8, it means that basically there will be 8 instances of the function with business logic.

Comment: @AntonioMiranda with setParallelism(1) it does work , but slow.